# Product in finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Product in finite abelian groups

Let $a\in A$ where $A$ is a finite abelian group.

> How do I prove that $\Pi_{x\in A}ax=\Pi_{x\in A}x$?

Thoughts:
If every element is not its own inverse, we see that $\Pi_{x\in A}x=e$. If there are elements that are their own inverse, then it is the product of these elements.
How do I get the identity above?

Comment: Show that the sets $\{x\mid x\in A\}$ and $\{ax\mid x\in A\}$ are equal.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How does the equality follow then?

Comment: Jose, since those sets are equal, up to commutativity, the equality becomes $x_1x_2\cdots x_n = x_1x_2\cdots x_n$, where $A = \{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$.

Answer (score 5):

The set $M:=\{ax\mid x\in A\}$ is equal to $A=\{x\mid x\in A\}$:

We have $M\subset A$. Also, for $y\in A$, we have $y=a(a^{-1}y)\in M$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do it.  You can group together all the factors of $a$ in the product $\prod_{x\in A}ax$ to get $a^{|A|}\prod_{x\in A}x$.  Now what can you say about $a^{|A|}$?

The answer is hidden below.

> We always have $a^{|A|}=1$, since the order of $a$ divides $|A|$.